# Convert Windows.Storage.StorageFile into javascript blob

Tags: javascript, c#, uwp, blob

How do I convert a StorageFile that could be any filetype using WinRT APIs into a Javascript blob or file?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't quite get what it is you're trying to accomplish. Can you add some more context please?

Comment: I'm using Windows.Storage.StorageFile.getFileFromPathAsync to get a StorageFile of a document, which I then want to convert into a File or a Blob (this is the format I need to pass into an unrelated function which then uploads this file to a service). Currently, at the end of all of my transformations I have an output that looks like gibberish ("AAAAAAAA...") and the file does not get uploaded.

Comment: I still don't quite get it. Have a look at the guide on [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly. A belated welcome to Stack Overflow too, by the way!